# Javascript: Remove duplicates in array of objects using a single property

Tags: javascript, object, duplicates

I have object like this where 'id', is unique. I need to remove duplicates from the array of objects in javascript in any version less than ES5. I need to compare based on the id field and remove its duplicates.

Example:

```
Object = [
{id: id_one, value: value_one, label: ABC},
{id: id_one, value: value_one, label: ABC},
{id: id_three, value: value_three, label: ABX},
{id: id_two, value: value_two, label: ABY},
{id: id_four, value: value_four, label: ABD}
];
```

Output:

```
result = [
{id: id_one, value: value_one, label: ABC},
{id: id_three, value: value_three, label: ABX},
{id: id_two, value: value_two, label: ABY},
{id: id_four, value: value_four, label: ABD}
];
```

I tried logic like this,

```
function getDistValues(object) {
  var distObject = [];
  var tempIndex = [];
  var length = object.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    tempIndex.push(object[i].id);

    if (tempIndex.indexOf(object[i].id) === -1 || i === 0) {
      distObject.push(object[i]);
    }
  }

  return distObject;
}
```

It is only giving the first object. I tried like mapping the ids and comparing it but not worked.

Any help will be useful to me.

Comment: You always do `tempIndex.push(object[i].id);` BEFORE checking  `tempIndex.indexOf(object[i].id)`, obviously it is always found. Also the best you would get from me is a babel transpile to ES3 from an ES2017 solution, because realistically, who writes ES3 these days?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are always adding the id to the `tempIndex` array, so it always thinks the current one is a duplicate. Try:

```
function getDistValues(object) {
  var distObject = [];
  var tempIndex = [];
  var length = object.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {    
    if (tempIndex.indexOf(object[i].id) === -1 || i === 0) {
      tempIndex.push(object[i].id);
      distObject.push(object[i]);
    }
  }

  return distObject;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for `id` property and filter if the `id` is not in the set.

```js
var array = [{ id: 'id_one', value: 'value_one', label: 'ABC' }, { id: 'id_one', value: 'value_one', label: 'ABC' }, { id: 'id_three', value: 'value_three', label: 'ABX' }, { id: 'id_two', value: 'value_two', label: 'ABY' }, { id: 'id_four', value: 'value_four', label: 'ABD' }],
    unique = array.filter((ids => ({ id }) => !ids.has(id) && ids.add(id))(new Set));

console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

An approach for older JS versions

```js
var array = [{ id: 'id_one', value: 'value_one', label: 'ABC' }, { id: 'id_one', value: 'value_one', label: 'ABC' }, { id: 'id_three', value: 'value_three', label: 'ABX' }, { id: 'id_two', value: 'value_two', label: 'ABY' }, { id: 'id_four', value: 'value_four', label: 'ABD' }],
    ids = {},
    unique = [],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (ids[array[i].id]) continue;
    unique.push(array[i]);
    ids[array[i].id] = true;
}

console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding items to the `tempIndex` array *before* you check if they are there. Since you always add each, then it's implicit that when you do the check the item will already be there.

You have to inverse this - check if an item exists *and then* add it to `tempIndex`

```js
var data = [
  {id: "id_one", value: "value_one", label: "ABC"},
  {id: "id_one", value: "value_one", label: "ABC"},
  {id: "id_three", value: "value_three", label: "ABX"},
  {id: "id_two", value: "value_two", label: "ABY"},
  {id: "id_four", value: "value_four", label: "ABD"}
];

function getDistValues(object) {
  var distObject = [];
  var tempIndex = [];
  var length = object.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    //check first
    var notSeen = tempIndex.indexOf(object[i].id) === -1;
    
    if (notSeen) {
      tempIndex.push(object[i].id);
      //add later
      distObject.push(object[i]);
    }
  }

  return distObject;
}

var result = getDistValues(data);

console.log(result);
```

In order to be more efficient, you can also use an object to keep the duplicate IDs - that will eliminate the need for another iteration over `tempIndex` every loop:

```js
var data = [
  {id: "id_one", value: "value_one", label: "ABC"},
  {id: "id_one", value: "value_one", label: "ABC"},
  {id: "id_three", value: "value_three", label: "ABX"},
  {id: "id_two", value: "value_two", label: "ABY"},
  {id: "id_four", value: "value_four", label: "ABD"}
];

function getDistValues(object) {
  var distObject = [];
  //use object
  var tempIndex = {};
  var length = object.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var notSeen = tempIndex[object[i].id] !== true;
    
    if (notSeen) {
      //mark as visited
      tempIndex[object[i].id] = true;
      distObject.push(object[i]);
    }
  }

  return distObject;
}

var result = getDistValues(data);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I find it funny, that when `exists` is true, it doesn't exist (not found).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by storing the `id` into an `object` and check if the `id` already exists in the `object`. If exists that means you've taken the object before. If not then push the object into a new array.

This approach takes `O(n)` time as we check from an object with constant time.

```js
var arr = [
    {id: 'id_one', value: 'value_one', label: 'ABC'},
    {id: 'id_one', value: 'value_one', label: 'ABC'},
    {id: 'id_three', value: 'value_three', label: 'ABX'},
    {id: 'id_two', value: 'value_two', label: 'ABY'},
    {id: 'id_four', value: 'value_four', label: 'ABD'}
];


function getDistValues(arr) {
 var hash = {};
    var uniqueArr = [];
    
 for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
         if (hash[arr[i].id] === undefined) {
         hash[arr[i].id] = 1;
                uniqueArr.push(arr[i]);
            } 
        }
    
    return uniqueArr;
}

console.log(getDistValues(arr));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` method for array with `Object.values` for filter duplicates

```js
const inputArray = [
    {id: 'id_one', value: 'value_one', label: 'ABC'},
    {id: 'id_one', value: 'value_one', label: 'ABC'},
    {id: 'id_three', value: 'value_three', label: 'ABX'},
    {id: 'id_two', value: 'value_two', label: 'ABY'},
    {id: 'id_four', value: 'value_four', label: 'ABD'}
    ]


      
const filterArray = (arr) => Object.values(arr.reduce(
  (acum, item) => {
    acum[item.id] = item
    return acum
  }, 
  {})
)

console.log(filterArray(inputArray))
```