# No need duplicate data to me, Please help me in this case: Id's are Duplicated, I need out as mentioned below

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, angular

Please find the below Data.

```
no need duplicate data to me, Please help me in this case:
Id's are Duplicated, i need output without duplicates:

Actual Data:
(9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    0: {Id: 0, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true},
    1: {Id: 1, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true},
    2: {Id: 2, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true},
    3: {Id: 3, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true},
    4: {Id: 4, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true},
    5: {Id: 1, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true},
    6: {Id: 2, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true},
    7: {Id: 3, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true},
    8: {Id: 4, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true}
    

I need Output Like this below:
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    0: {Id: 0, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true},
    1: {Id: 1, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true},
    2: {Id: 2, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true},
    3: {Id: 3, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true},
    4: {Id: 4, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true}
```

I need output as above
I need output as above
I need output as above
I need output as above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Remove duplicates in array of objects using a single property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61016338/javascript-remove-duplicates-in-array-of-objects-using-a-single-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate and check whether updating array have existing Id using [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const inputData = [ {Id: 0, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true},
    {Id: 1, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true},
    {Id: 2, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true},
    {Id: 3, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true},
    {Id: 4, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true},
    {Id: 1, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true},
    {Id: 2, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true},
    {Id: 3, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true},
    {Id: 4, Specialization: "General", Description: "General", IsActive: true}]

let output = [];
    inputData.forEach(val => {
 var isExist = output.some(data => data.Id === val.Id);
 if(!isExist) output.push(val)
})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just going to filter by `Id`, use `reduce` and `Object.values`:

```
const output = Object.values(data.reduce((a, { Id, ...o }) => {
  a[Id] = a[Id] || { Id, ...o };
  return a;
}, {}));
```

```js
const data = [{Id:0,Specialization:"General",Description:"General",IsActive:true},{Id:1,Specialization:"General",Description:"General",IsActive:true},{Id:2,Specialization:"General",Description:"General",IsActive:true},{Id:3,Specialization:"General",Description:"General",IsActive:true},{Id:4,Specialization:"General",Description:"General",IsActive:true},{Id:1,Specialization:"General",Description:"General",IsActive:true},{Id:2,Specialization:"General",Description:"General",IsActive:true},{Id:3,Specialization:"General",Description:"General",IsActive:true},{Id:4,Specialization:"General",Description:"General",IsActive:true}];

const output = Object.values(data.reduce((a, { Id, ...o }) => {
  a[Id] = a[Id] || { Id, ...o };
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below of code:

```
let uniqueArray= Array.from(duplicateArray.reduce((m, t) => m.set(t.Id, t), new Map()).values());
console.log(uniqueArray);
```